# Java error, please help me out

Tags: java, compiler-errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unsupported major.minor version 49.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525960/unsupported-major-minor-version-49-0)

Alright guys, I just installed JDK 7, and I'm on windows 7. I'm just trying to get a simple "hello world" to compile and run, which I copied from somewhere because I don't know exactly what I'm doing yet. I've set up the PATH already, and when I use javac I think it compiles without giving an error but when I try to run it, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: apples : Unsu
pported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: apples.  Program will exit.
```

Don't know if that helps any lol but thanks for anyone who knows whats going on here.

java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01, mixed mode)

javac 1.7.0_04

Comment: Type `java -version` and `javac -version` and paste the results into your question.

Comment: You are compiling with one version, and running with another. Which .. googling that error would tell you.

Comment: @Brian Roach No, I tried that and never found a solution, which is why I posted here. Thanks for the help. But yeah I see whats wrong now.

Comment: @Satya `which java` is the linux/unix command. In Windows 7 it's `where java`.

Comment: mea culpa truth, I am deleting my earlier comment

Answer (score 1):

This answer is probably redundant, but the problem is that the JVM *that you are using to run the program* is not the Java 7 JVM that you just installed.  It is an older one, and it doesn't understand the (Java 7) .class file that you asked it to run.

Greg Hewgill suggested that you run `java -version` and `javac -version`.  These will tell you what version of Java you are *actually* running ... as distinct from the version you *think* you are running.

The solution is (probably) is to update your `%PATH%` which is currently pointing at an older java install.

---

The output from `java -version` and `javac -version` that you added to your question means that you are compiling with Java 7 and running with Java 6.  That is definitely the cause of your problem.  Fix your `%PATH` variables so that you compile and run with the same toolsets.  (That's the simplest solution ...)

Comment: I've got it working now, updated everything to Java 7. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

see you are using jdk6 to run and jdk7 to compile , you will have to change your path/classpath settings to reflect jdk7