# Getting error while deploying WAR file

Tags: war

I am getting below error while deploying war file .Here JDK version on development machine and deployment machines is same then also i am getting this error.

[05/Jun/2013:11:20:42] failure ( 5712): WebModule[/cover]: WEB2671: Error configuring application listener of class com.bt.cover.ContextListener
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/bt/cover/ContextListener (Unsupported major.minor version 49.0)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:537)
            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:123)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1717)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:983)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1431)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1301)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3349)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3743)
            at com.iplanet.ias.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:251)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1133)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:652)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1133)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:355)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:995)
            at com.iplanet.ias.web.WebContainer.start(WebContainer.java:431)
            at com.iplanet.ias.web.WebContainer.startInstance(WebContainer.java:500)
            at com.iplanet.ias.server.J2EERunner.confPostInit(J2EERunner.java:161)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this answer: [Unsupported major.minor version 49.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525960/unsupported-major-minor-version-49-0), it looks like you may be running on a different JVM from what you used to compile your code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hii...here jre version is same on development machine and deployment machine.

Comment: Just so I'm sure I understand, are you saying the JDK you used to compile your code is the same version as the JRE that you're using to to run your application?

Comment: I agree with David. Make sure if you are compiling in Windows (then in Windows machine's JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to JDK x.x) then the same or later version of JDK should be set while deploying this application. JDK x+N.x+N should be backward compatible but in vice versa case, will give you the error you are getting.