# Is possible to use JXLS with java 1.4?

Tags: java, jxls

The server java machine that I'm using is java 1.4 and I need to work with excel templates...can I use jxls? I'm geting this error: net/sf/jxls/transformer/XLSTransformer (Unsupported major.minor version 49.0)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unsupported major.minor version 49.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525960/unsupported-major-minor-version-49-0)

Comment: I'm only want to know the min version of java to use jxls...

Comment: See my answer and vote it correct if applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've solved the problem. I've needed to use next libraries:

- POI 3.2
- JXLS 0.9.8
- JEXL 1.0
- POI OOXML 3.12
- ORG APACHE COMMONS LOGGING

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can , just try any version of JXLS1.x which fits with Java1.4. I see that the very first version of JXLS has a major version of 46.

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\Check\jxls-0.7\org\jxls>javap -verbose CellInfo| fin
dstr "major"
  major version: 46

C:\Users\id831496\Downloads\Check\jxls-0.7\org\jxls>
```

Try using `1.0-RC-1` from the below link

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jxls/files/jxls/

Comment: Hi Kalyan! You're solution it's fine, because I can use this jxls library with java 1.4, but right now, I have a new problem with other library, dependent of jxls. This library is POI. I've seen POI minor than 3.5 are the only one that I could use with java 1.4, but I have a new problem... java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook. If I use POI 3.5 -> org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory (Unsupported major.minor version 49.0)
and if I use POI 3.2 -> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook. Do you think there is solution?

Comment: Whats the exact problem ? What's with using POI 3.5 in your project ?

Comment: I'm trying to write some values in an excel template, using jxls. If I use POI 3.5, I have the java server problem, but on the other side, if I use POI 3.2 I can't compile the project because I don't have the WorkbookFactory class...

Comment: I guess you can try this.... This is apache poi 3.8 version, converted to Java 1.4 .... http://en.osdn.jp/projects/poi-jdk14/releases/

Comment: And please vote my answer correct if it works for you :)

Comment: Hi Kalyan, thank you so much again. I'm googling and I found this library too. I've proved to use it, but I have the same problem...it doesn't exist the Workbook class...the conflictive lines of my code are these: XLSTransformer transformer = new XLSTransformer();
       transformer.transformXLS(args4, beans, args5); I'm going to looking for another way to resolve it. I'll tell you my progession later ;)